# How I can delete objects from array when their property value is in another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have this array with IDs:

```
const idsArr = [1,2,3]
```

And I have also an array with objects, like this:

```
const arrOfObj = [
  {id: 1, name: 'a'},
  {id: 2, name: 'b'},
  {id: 3, name: 'c'},
  {id: 4, name: 'd'},
  {id: 5, name: 'e'},
]
```

How I can filter `arrOfObj` and get only those objects whose `id` values are not included in `idsArr`?

Expected result:

```
[     
  {id: 4, name: 'd'},
  {id: 5, name: 'e'}
]
```

Comment: `arrOfObj.filter((o) => !idsArr.includes(o.id));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var result = arrOfObj.filter(a => !idsArr.includes(a.id));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a set (for better efficiency), and then... filter:

```js
const arrOfObj = [ {id: 1, name: 'a'}, {id: 2, name: 'b'}, {id: 3, name: 'c'}, {id: 4, name: 'd'}, {id: 5, name: 'e'},];

let set = new Set([1,2,3]);
let result = arrOfObj.filter(({id}) => !set.has(id));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple if you know array methods

It can be done like this

```
function filterArrayWithId(arrOfObj, idsArr) {
  arrOfObj.filter(obj => !idsArr.includes(obj.id))
}
```

Comment down on any doubts